# product export from magento 1.9.3 no longer possible

Tags: product, export, magento1.9.3

I started with a magento 1.9.2 installation. It was possible to import/export the products with the magento funtion export/data profile/export all products.

A few weeks ago, I upgraded to magento 1.9.3. When I tried to export all products now I only see a white new tab.

After a few minutes I get an error message

> "unavailable service due to .... or capacity problem"

I use magento 1.9.3 with mariadb 10.0 / plesk.

Answer (score 0):

Go to app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Entity/Product.php

replace

```
$dataRow += $stockItemRows[$productId];
with 
$dataRow = array_merge($dataRow,$stockItemRows[$productId]);
```